# Cytoscape js create custom renderer (renderer extension)

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape, custom-renderer

Please can anyone help me with creation of a renderer extension for cytoscape js lib.

Here is how it is working now:

```js
let CanvasRenderer = cytoscape('renderer', 'canvas');

CanvasRenderer.prototype.drawPolygonPath = function(context, x, y, width, height, points) {
  // my implementation goes here
}
```

As it says on [cytoscape site](http://js.cytoscape.org/) it is an extensible library! As i'm using typescript in my project i want something like this:

```js
class MyRenderer {

    constructor() {
        
    }
}

cytoscape('renderer', 'myRenderer', MyRenderer);
```

This code obviously throws cytoscape error that says that i have not implemented some methods...

Then i found an extension [cytoscape-css-renderer](https://github.com/wehriam/cytoscape-css-renderer) and it did not work with my version of cytoscape (i'm using 2.7.13)
I've also tried to solve this problem similar to the cytoscape-css-renderer:

```js
let CanvasRenderer = cytoscape('renderer', 'canvas');

class MyRenderer {

    constructor(options) {
        CanvasRenderer.call(options);
    }

}

MyRenderer.prototype = Object.create(CanvasRenderer.prototype);
MyRenderer.prototype.constructor = MyRenderer;
$.extend(PricingRenderer, CanvasRenderer);

cytoscape('renderer', 'myRenderer', MyRenderer);
```

but it throws this error:

Can not register `myRenderer` for `renderer` since `clientFunctions` already exists in the prototype and can not be overridden

So can someone help me with this... Thank you!

Comment: Looks like drawpolygonpath needs to be defined

Comment: Can you please tell me how to call drawPolygonpath from cytoscape canvas? any demo?

Answer (score 1):

Use the canvas renderer as an example: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/tree/master/src/extensions/renderer/canvas